# Trying to make my main/java class files to compile to a .jar, and then produce a .war also

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a spring application (MVC) that I built using IntelliJ.
I am using Maven.

My pom.xml file currently produces a war file when I run:

```
mvn clean install
```

pom.xml:

```
 <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Now I want to avoid creating 2 different solutions if possible.

All my code in /src/main/java has a package name:

```
com.myapp
```

I want all of these classes to be in a com.myapp.jar file.

Also during the maven install process, I want it to then add this com.myapp.jar to the /lib path when it creates a .war file so I can deploy to tomcat/jetty.

Can someone outline exactly what I have to do, I'm confused how I can do both of these things at once.

Currently my pom.xml's build section looks like:

```
<build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>${java-version}</source>
                   <target>${java-version}</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.1.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <warName>myapp</warName>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.1</version>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>6.1.26</version>
               <configuration>
                   <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                   <contextPath>/</contextPath>

               </configuration>

           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear, but if you want to archive your classes and put the classes in the lib directory of the WAR file. If this is what you are looking at the below plugin does the same:

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
      </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: I want my code to go in a seperate .jar file, and then use that .jar file in my .war file.  this way I can re-use that .jar file if I need to.

Comment: The archive classes creates a compiled classes jar file and copies the jar to the WEB-INF/lib directory. If the archiveClasses is not set to true, all the compiled classes would land up in the WEB-INF/classes. Is this what you are looking at or do you want to create a jar file containing the source (.java) files?

Answer (score 0):

You should create two maven projects. One, for the jar with just the classes you want in the jar and second maven project for the war. In the war project, jar project should be added as a dependency.

Also, if you want to install war project and at the same time to produce that jar file (just in one command line) you should define the war project as the parent project and the jar one as a module. See [doc](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) and tags `<parent>...</parent>` and `<modules>...</modules>`.

So, parent pom should have a module tag and module pom should hava a parent tag. When you run mvn install over the parent project (war one) maven automatically will run first the command over the module. See also this maven multiproject [doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/reactor.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your need is to make your project modular, bundle your src/main/java with a pom and package it as jar, then create another web project with another pom and add this already created project as module. So, your parent pom should have a module like this:

```
<modules>
        <module>core</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Explained here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached